# Pagination does not work properly - will_paginate, bootstrap4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, will-paginate

I am new on Rails. Trying to add will_paginate in my project, followed the instructions and added the configurations accordingly. Finally it works and shows the page numbers.

1.) The problem is that when it shows the pages number and next page option it does not include the space between numbers.

[image]

[image]

2.) is there any way to use will_paginate bootstrap with bootstrap 4? bkz as i know the guy mentioned he dont provide support for that gem anymore.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for, I have used it but don't know if it supports bootstrap 4 https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/will_paginate-bootstrap

Comment: i tried it but its not working. and the guy wrote big Note: that he stoped support for bootstrap

Comment: I've never used the paginate bootstrap gem, I just followed the advice here and it worked fine for me... http://mislav.github.io/will_paginate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there any way to use will_paginate bootstrap with bootstrap 4? bkz as i know the guy mentioned he dont provide support for that gem anymore.

Here is the `will_paginate` support with `bootstrap 4` [will_paginate-bootstrap4](https://github.com/delef/will_paginate-bootstrap4)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering has absolutely nothing to do with Ruby/Rails: It's merely a CSS issue. will_paginate makes no assumptions about the styling of your pagination section and simply outputs unstyled HTML tags. It's then your responsibility to style it according to your liking – e.g. with Bootstrap, like you've mentioned.

And generally, I suggest using [Kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari) instead of will_paginate: I think it makes more sense for a pagination solution to use regular templates instead of rendering all the HTML using helper methods. But that's just my opinion after using will_paginate for more than a decade and Kaminari almost since it came out 6 1/2 years ago.

Comment: actually Will_paginate supposed to add css automatically in your project. but since teh support for bootsrap4 was missing by that gem that was teh problem. but now i found a new gem which supports  new bootstrap. but thanks

Answer (score 0):

since you can see the number it seems your bootstrap 4 is working already you just need to make CSS styles to make those pagination links prettier, here is source [css for will_paginate](http://mislav.github.io/will_paginate/)

to customize how it views below is sample or will_paginate scss file
you can create one scss file inside app/stylesheets/will_paginate.scss and put the code below

```
.digg_pagination {
  background: #FFFFFF; 
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: default;
  /* self-clearing method: */ }
  .digg_pagination a, .digg_pagination span, .digg_pagination em {
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px; }
  .digg_pagination .disabled {
    color: #999999;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd; }
  .digg_pagination .current {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #2e6ab1;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #2e6ab1; }
  .digg_pagination a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #105cb6;
    border: 1px solid #9aafe5; }
    .digg_pagination a:hover, .digg_pagination a:focus {
      color: #000033;
      border-color: #000033; }
  .digg_pagination .page_info {
    background: #2e6ab1;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
    width: 22em;
    margin-bottom: 0.3em;
    text-align: center; }
    .digg_pagination .page_info b {
      color: #000033;
      background: #6aa6ed;
      padding: 0.1em 0.25em; }
  .digg_pagination:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden; }
  * html .digg_pagination {
    height: 1%; }
  *:first-child + html .digg_pagination {
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```